# PHP doesn't want to print sql results,it is printing only empty divs

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with my php code which is used to find if there is a match in a database from thing you write in an input field,and if there are results print them out in a HTML elements.

But instead of returning the resulting values,it is printing only the HTML elements there is how it looks like:[CLICK !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeJcZ.png)

[image]

And there is the code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['fsearch'])) {
   $fsearch = $_POST['fsearch'];
   $req = $connect->prepare("SELECT title FROM food_data_bg WHERE title LIKE ?");
   $value = '%'.$fsearch.'%';
   $req->bind_param('s', $value);
   $req->execute();
   $req->store_result();
   if ($req->num_rows == 0){
      echo 'Няма резултати';
   } else{
      while($row = $req->fetch()){
   ?>
   <div class="search-result">
       <span class="result-title"><?php echo $row['title'] ;?></span>
   </div>
   <?php
   }
}
}
```

So i tried with different fetch methods,till i read somewhere that mysqli supports only fetch if you don't have plugin for fetch_assoc and other methods installed.Tried only with 1 value,it is the same result,nothing inside the span element.I am not really sure do i need to declare a $row as something for it to work.I am really confused about all things which might be a mistake,thats why i am asking here,because i am finding help here every time

Comment: `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);?>` add it on your page on top and then check. May be you will get some error

Comment: can you do a var_dump($row) after your [while] statement and tell us what the $row object contains?

Comment: In your query you are selecting only 'title' while in loop you are also displaying 'fimage' and 'calories_total'. fix this first

Comment: Acriel It says NULL   

                           

B.Desai It is fixed now,will fix it in here too.

Comment: PHP's `mysqli::fetch()` method returns a _boolean_, not an associative array. Simply read the documentation of the tools you use and take a look at the examples: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: Oooh,yap my bad i am reading from like 3 hours for different fetch methods,but for something like fetch_assoc i need a plugin installed and i decided to short my way and do not installing this plugin but instead use mysqli::fetch because it is ready to use,so i guess its my lazyness that tricked me here.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents, but have you tried running this without `$req->store_result();` ?

**EDIT:**

You're correct. Based on the comment of arkascha, this code should work:

```
if(!empty($_POST['fsearch'])) {
    $fsearch = $_POST['fsearch'];
    $req = $connect->prepare("SELECT title FROM food_data_bg WHERE title LIKE ?");
    $value = '%'.$fsearch.'%';
    $req->bind_param('s', $value);
    $req->execute();
    $req->store_result();
    if ($req->num_rows == 0){
        echo 'Няма резултати';
    } else{
        $req->bind_result($title);
        while($req->fetch()){
            ?>
            <div class="search-result">
                <span class="result-title"><?php echo $title;?></span>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yap and it is giving me undefined variable row on line 32
So it is ` while($row = $req->fetch()){ ...} `

Comment: new error with this code : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE)

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that if $row is a value or offer something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it i just needed to bind_result("and use here my param from sql") And just print the binded result,but it need to be after the store_result(); and out of if,else statements otherwise it won't work,as i understand after 8 hours of trying LOL

Here is how final Code looks like:

```html
if(!empty($_POST['fsearch'])) {
$fsearch = $_POST['fsearch'];

$req = $connect->prepare("SELECT title FROM food_data_bg WHERE title LIKE ?");
$value = '%'.$fsearch.'%';
$req->bind_param('s', $value);
$req->execute();
$req->store_result();
$num_of_rows = $req->num_rows;
$req->bind_result($title);
if ($req->num_rows == 0){

echo 'Няма резултати';
}
else{
while($data=$req->fetch()){
   ?>
       <div class="search-result">
           <span class="result-title"><?php echo $title; ?></span>
       </div>
       <?php
       }
$req->free_result();
    }
}
```

Now the only problem is that when you type something on cyrillic it doesn't return result.But guess that would be another question open if i cannot find fix for it too.Thank you guys <3 AGAIN !